# android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView does not work

Tags: android, geometry, material-design

when I try to use :
android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bg" />
```

it makes my app crash

how to support new Material Design Widget CircleImageView

is there any example use this new widget

Logcat

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vogella.android.recyclerview/com.vogella.android.recyclerview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView
        at
```

Comment: this is my logcat my friend

Comment: is there any example use this new widget

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found a replacement for android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/meal_image_order"
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:src="@drawable/menu1"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Library link: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: In that link I did not see the library to download, just source code. Can you please give more details on how to add this custom view to an app?

Comment: @Zvi you must be using gradle. it is mentioned here https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#gradle

Comment: @Abhishek I know that and I have added to my gradle 'compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0''. But it needs a file (maybe a jar or a libraray) for circleimageview. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Zvi just do project build gradle will automatically add the required files to your project.

Comment: @Abhishek I did as you said (add the compile directive to my gradle, built my project, and run it and got exception 'Error inflating class talkie.feedback.circleimageview.CircleImageView'. Also on compile I got and error 'Error:(128) No resource identifier found for attribute 'border_width' in package ..' and the same for border_color

Comment: What exception are you getting? Better put a separate question explaining what you tried and what error you are getting.

Comment: I added the exception

Comment: did you Update gradle plugin and build tools to latest versions

Comment: Found the option but how do I update to the latest version of the build tools

Comment: My home entry is 'D:/Downloads/android-studio-ide-143.2739321-windows/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.10'

Comment: From your SDK Manager

Comment: My SDK is up to date. Maybe you can guide step by step

Comment: I downloaded gradle version 2.13 and update build tools and manage to solve the exception, but I still get the errors regarding attributes border_width and border_color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110861/discussion-between-zvi-and-maher-ismaail).

Comment: @Zvi `talkie.feedback.circleimageview.CircleImageView` what are you doing, the library is called `<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` it says so in the answer, of course it doesn't work if you specify a non-existent view!

Comment: Replace `app:border_width="2dp"
app:border_color="@color/white"` by `app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"` to work

Comment: Before switching to  `de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView` please see [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#limitations) . It wont work if you want to scale image to fitXY or any other than centerCrop

Comment: @ChamanSaini, It has worked by adding tags that you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 55):

The `CircleImageView` is a private class of the support library and cannot be used. But it is easy to create this effect yourself without the `CircleImageView`. You just need to define a `<shape />` drawable with a transparent circle in the middle similar to this:

```
<shape
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="100dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

After that just combine the image you want to display in the `ImageView` with the `<shape />` drawable from above in a `LayerList` like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle" />
</layer-list>
```

If the image you want to display is dynamic then you can create the `LayerList` programmatically!

Comment: @MaherIsmaail You can't just edit somebody else's answer like that. I have rolled back the edit for now.

Answer (score 19):

`CircleImageView` is a private class from `v4`, so basically you can't use it. It is used internally for rendering the progress circle in a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, but is not meant to be inflated by yourself.

See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v4/widget/CircleImageView.java/) for reference.

Comment: It is used internally in the SwipeRefreshLayout. If you just need a image view with a circle outline, there are a lot of questions here on SO.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it in a native style just use this snippet

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:shape="ring"
                app:cardCornerRadius="23dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_img_post"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_img"></ImageView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your answer is good hack. But `android:shape="ring"` is do nothing here. Just put `app:cardCornerRadius="1000dp"` (put higher) did the trick. **You deserved higher upvote.**

Comment: Oh i was never aware of this property! Cool stuff!

Comment: It works, but there is a point to make. Adding this to display multiple circles on a `RecyclerView` item may have a performance impact. So be careful. But anyway this is a nice solution

Answer (score 6):

Simple add: Here Change latest Library version `2.0.0` to `2.2.0`

```
dependencies {

 implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

}
```

Comment: i tried the newest version of the `circleimageview` still not working.

Comment: you can try try it :<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
               android:id="@+id/iv_circle"
               android:layout_width="96dp"
               android:layout_height="96dp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:src="@drawable/thumb"
               app:border_color="@color/white"
               app:border_width="2dp" />

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me

xml layout:

```
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/picid"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            />
```

Java code:

```
CircleImageView pic = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.picid);
```

Comment: its a third party library example...question is about to `android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView`

Answer (score 3):

Just Rebuild the project

- Build ===> Clear Project
- Build ===> Rebuild Project

**and if not works** 
File ===> Invaildate Cahses / Restart

Then it will Work.

Answer (score 1):

**dependency:**

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

**code:**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
               android:id="@+id/iv_circle"
               android:layout_width="96dp"
               android:layout_height="96dp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:src="@drawable/thumb"
               app:border_color="@color/white"
               app:border_width="2dp" />
```